# Angular Material: MAT-NAV-LIST with keyboard navigation

Tags: angular, angular-material

So after almost completing our MVP we are now working on accessibility of our app, one of the most important bits is the navigation.

we are using simple `<mat-nav-list>` component with `mat-list-item`s inside that each has a `routerLink`.

something like this:

```
<mat-nav-list id="app-nav" tabindex="1" aria-label="Main navigation">
  <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['user-account']">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>badge</mat-icon>
    <span mat-line>Your profile</span>
  </mat-list-item>
  ...
</mat-nav-list>
```

Now, navigating with a `TAB` key works fine, what it doesn't to my surprise is pressing `ENTER` (or `SPACE`) which should trigger the (normal click) or routerLink (as it does on normal links).

The next bit is navigating with ARROW keys up and down.... it does not... but if I would be to use mat-selection-list, with mat-list-option... the keyboard navigation works (similarly it works on mat-menu.

How can I make mat-item being triggered by enter key (without putting keydown.enter on every item... or putting ) and make it accessible with arrow keys?

I also tried with Material's CDK ListKeyManager

```
private keyManager!: ListKeyManager<MatListItem>;
```

but the lack of documentation and examples is spinning my head... seems like there is no way to do this since it needs a focus interface and I cannot implement it in mat-list-item component...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `mat-nav-list`, you can directly use `<a>` element  along with `mat-list-item` attribute specified on it as below:

```html
<mat-nav-list id="app-nav" aria-label="Main navigation">
  <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['user-account']">
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>badge</mat-icon>
    <span mat-line>Your profile</span>
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

[Accessibility - Navigation](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#navigation) section from docs:

> You should use MatNavList when every item in the list is an anchor that navigate to another URL. The root <mat-nav-list> element sets role="navigation" and should contain only anchor elements with the mat-list-item attribute. You should not nest any interactive elements inside these anchors, including buttons and checkboxes.

[Navigation lists](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#navigation-lists)

Comment: Yeah, great man! this worked very well! never thought of using mat-list-item directive for it.... what about keyboard UP/DOWN?

Comment: @DS_web_developer Why do you want to navigate via keyboard UP/DOWN arrows? When it comes to links, we navigate them via TAB only, and not UP/DOWN arrows. Navigation lists are different from Selection lists.

Comment: it is a navigation menu! Like all menus it needs to be accessible by key navigation up and down. Tabs is bare minimum

Comment: @DS_web_developer So why are you not using `mat-menu`? It will provide you the [Keyboard interactions](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#keyboard-interaction) you are looking for and may also make more sense.

Comment: because mat-menu needs a trigger to open

Comment: I am not sure how you are using it within your application. But if it's a top navigation menu, then obviously it will require a trigger to open. And if you are using it as sidebar navigation (like we have on angular.io guide page or material.angular.io components page), then the navigation is usually via TAB key only.

Comment: yeah... it is side navigation like on angular material's page

Answer (score 0):

Set tabindex for every menu item or put this part inside a button or a tag

```
<button .....>
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>badge</mat-icon>
    <span mat-line>Your profile</span>
</button>
```

or

```
<a ...>
    <mat-icon mat-list-icon>badge</mat-icon>
    <span mat-line>Your profile</span>
</a>
```

Comment: why would I do that? mat-na-list does not allow any buttons in mat-list-items.... also 'tabbing' works fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add *ListKeyManager* for keyboard navigation to an Angular Material navigation list. Only the *MatSelectionList* and it's *MatListOption* seems to implement the correct interface.

You're probably better off creating your own list and list item components. Here is an article explaining how to do that. It also links to a Stackblitz example.

[Doing A11y easily with Angular CDK. Keyboard-Navigable Lists](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/doing-a11y-easily-with-angular-cdk-keyboard-navigable-lists-d32f458b8851)

Answer (score 0):

I did an implementation of `mat-nav-list` with keyboard navigation via Angular `FocusKeyManager`.

As stated in docs, `FocusKeyManager` is used when options will directly receive browser focus. Each item managed must implement the `FocusableOption` extends ListKeyManagerOption interface`:

```js
interface FocusableOption extends ListKeyManagerOption {
  focus(): void;
}

this.keyManager = new FocusKeyManager(this.items).withWrap();
```

Considering that we have a `mat-nav-list` that contains several `mat-list-item` with `routerLink`:

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item
     [routerLink]="[item.route]"
     routerLinkActive
     #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [activated]="rla.isActive">
    <span matListItemTitle>{{ item.title }}</span>
    <mat-icon matListItemIcon>{{ item.icon }}</mat-icon>
  </a>

  //...   
  
</mat-nav-list>
```

At this point, we need to:

- make `mat-list-item` to implement `FocusableOption` interface
- initialize `FocusKeyManager` at `mat-nav-list` level.

This can be done using two custom directives: `appListItemFocusable` and `appNavListKeyManager`, which will be attached to `mat-list-item` and `mat-nav-list` respectively.

```html
<mat-nav-list appNavListKeyManager>
  <a mat-list-item appListItemFocusable 
    [routerLink]="..." //..>
     //...
  </a>

  //...
</mat-nav-list>
```

**appListItemFocusable**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appListItemFocusable]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ListItemFocusable
  implements FocusableOption, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy
{
  /** Stream that emits when the item is focused. */
  public readonly focused = new Subject<ListItemFocusable>();

  constructor(
    public readonly elementRef: ElementRef,
    public readonly focusMonitor: FocusMonitor
  ) {}

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Start monitoring the element so it gets the appropriate focused classes.
    this.focusMonitor.monitor(this.elementRef, false).subscribe((origin) => {
      if (origin) {
        this.focused.next(this);
      }
    });
  }

  public focus(origin?: FocusOrigin, options?: FocusOptions): void {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus(options);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.focusMonitor.stopMonitoring(this.elementRef);
    this.focused.complete();
  }
}
```

**appNavListKeyManager**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appNavListKeyManager]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class NavListKeyManager implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ContentChildren(ListItemFocusable)
  private items!: QueryList<ListItemFocusable>;

  private keyManager!: FocusKeyManager<ListItemFocusable>;

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const activeItem = this.keyManager.activeItem;
    // Handle SPACE keypress 
    if (event.keyCode === SPACE) {
      if (activeItem) {
        activeItem.elementRef.nativeElement.click();
      }
    } else {
      this.keyManager.setFocusOrigin('keyboard');
      this.keyManager.onKeydown(event);
    }
  }

  constructor() {}

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.keyManager = new FocusKeyManager(this.items).withWrap();

    // If a user manually (programatically) focuses an item, we need to reflect that focus change back to the key manager.
    this.items.changes
      .pipe(
        startWith(this.items),
        switchMap((items) =>
          merge<ListItemFocusable[]>(
            ...items.map((item: ListItemFocusable) => item.focused)
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((focusedItem) => {
        this.keyManager.updateActiveItem(focusedItem);
      });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.keyManager.destroy();
  }
}
```

**Stackblitz DEMO**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cjlt4h

---

`FocusKeyManager` documentation on **Angular Material** *(still poor)*: https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#listkeymanager

The implementation is inspired from **Angular Material Menu Component**:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/17.0.x/src/material/menu/menu.ts